# Mongo aggregate that returns last version of each set of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents in a collection called sampledata:

```
sampledata:
{
    "link" : "demo-1",
    "type" : "type-1",
    "version" : 1,
    "slug" : "slug-1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550acc38fd15150c290dd489")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-2",
    "type" : "type-2",
    "version" : 1,
    "slug" : "slug-2",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550acc37fd15150c290dd46a")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-3",
    "type" : "type-3",
    "version" : 1,
    "slug" : "slug-3",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550acc38fd15150c290dd46e")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-3",
    "type" : "type-3",
    "version" : 2,
    "slug" : "slug-3",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550b6182dac1909834b7b38d")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-3",
    "type" : "type-3",
    "version" : 3,
    "slug" : "slug-3",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550b61d3dac1909834b7b38e")
}
```

I need an aggregate pipeline that returns the last "version" of each "type" of document.  Thus, the results should be:

```
{
    "link" : "demo-1",
    "type" : "type-1",
    "version" : 1,
    "slug" : "slug-1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550acc38fd15150c290dd489")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-2",
    "type" : "type-2",
    "version" : 1,
    "slug" : "slug-2",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550acc37fd15150c290dd46a")
}
{
    "link" : "demo-3",
    "type" : "type-3",
    "version" : 3,
    "slug" : "slug-3",
    "_id" : ObjectId("550b61d3dac1909834b7b38e")
}
```

The following gives me most of what I want but I'm having a hard time returning the rest of the fields in the selected documents as-is:

```
db.sampledata.aggregate([{"$group": { "_id": "$slug", lastVersion: {"$last":"$version"} } }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator works in the "last" item in a grouping boundary from the supplied key. Typically it is used with [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) preceeding the following [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement. This "orders" the documents in the collection in the desired way, so that the "last" picks up what is expected:

```js
db.sampledata.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "slug": 1, "version": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$slug",
        "link": { "$last": "$link" },
        "type": { "$last": "$type" },
        "version": { "$last": "$version" },
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" }
    }}
])
```

As you see, the intent is to use the operator against each of the fields if you want to match the whole document that was "last" in that order. To fully reconstruct you need a following [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```js
db.sampledata.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "slug": 1, "version": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$slug",
        "link": { "$last": "$link" },
        "type": { "$last": "$type" },
        "version": { "$last": "$version" },
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "slug": "$_id",
        "link": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "version": 1
    }}
])
```